# Is there a way to create Span using SpanContext which is NOT no-op

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I have a traceId from upstream which i need to use to use to create Span in my task .

So , i created SpanContext using the upstream traceId and a generated spanid and then created a Span by using Span.wrap(SpanContext)

However , both this span and any subsequent span creatied using this span as parent becomes no-op

is there a better way to achieve this? (create a Span using a traceId from upstream)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind , the reason was i was using TracerFlags.getDefault() in which sampled is set to false